# Create action - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters, cocoon-gem

When I try to puts out the strong params in console, the server does not respond, not even a error. Nothing. And the create action does not work. Any idea? I'm using cocoon in the form I'm trying to submit.

Thanks,

```
def new
    @game = Game.new
    @level = @game.levels.build
end

def create

 @game = Game.new(game_params)

 puts @game

 if @game.save
   redirect_to @game, notice: 'Game was successfully created.'
 else
       render :new
    end
end

private

def game_params
  params.require(:game).permit(:name, :publisher, :year, :description, :image, levels_attributes: [:id, :name, :sort_order, :_destroy])
end
```

My game class

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :levels

accepts_nested_attributes_for :levels, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true

mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader

end
```

Comment: Are you sure that the `create` action is executed by the request? What if you added `puts 'Hi'` at the beginning of the method? Does that output to the console?

Comment: In addition to what @ChrisPeters asked, can you post your Game class?

Comment: @ChrisPeters

Thanks for your hel, guys. I notice something weird. At the first time I load my form, the submit does not work, even if I just puts "Hi" to the console. But if I reload the page, the form works with no problem. But only after the reload.

Comment: Hrm...Ok that was not quite as helpful as I had hoped xD. It just occurred to me but the form is on your "new" page, correct? It sounds like either your `def new...end` command is messing up, or your new view page isn't properly set up. Can you post those as well? (sorry to be asking for so much stuff xD)

Comment: @Micah, of course I can. I appreciate your help very much. I'm gonna edit the code above.

Comment: UPDATE: When I access through URL (http://localhost:3000/games/new), form works well. But when I use the link in my nav (<%= link_to "New game", new_game_path  %>) bar, the problems occurs.

Comment: When clicking the link in the nav, is it taking you to localhost:3000/games/new? Is it the same URL as what you're visiting manually? What path is `new_game_path` generating?

Comment: I appreciate all your help. The answer is: turbolinks :-/ I removed turbolinks and now it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the actual rails console, of course none of that would show up there.

Review http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#the-logger, then change your puts to something more appropriate, like:

```
logger.warn("game: #{@game.inspect}")
```

Comment: Same thing happens. The first time I load the form, the submit button does not work. Only after refresh. After refreshing, everything works just well.

Comment: UPDATE: When I access through URL (localhost:3000/games/new), form works well. But when I use the link in my nav (<%= link_to "New game", new_game_path %>) bar, the problems occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate all your help. The answer is: turbolinks :-/ I removed turbolinks and now it works just fine.